# Finding the author of a line of code in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How do I find out who is responsible for a specific line of code? I know the linenumber and the filename but I would like Mercurial to tell me the author(s) of that specific line of code. Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

On the command-line, you'd want to use `hg annotate -u` (`-u` can be combined with `-n` to get the local revision number, which might come in useful). Check `hg help anno` for more options.

Comment: I believe that originates with SVN.

Comment: CVS called it `annotate`. In SVN, the primary for the command is `blame`, although `annotate` and `praise` are available as aliases.

Comment: To clarify: this shows who was the last to _edit_ the line, not necessarily who originally created it.

Answer (score 38):

I was a fan of `"svn blame"`, so I've added to my `~/.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
blame = annotate --user --number
```

so I can just type `"hg blame"` ;-)

Comment: BTW hg blame is a default command, as far as I can tell. I don't know if it's just recent, but it's there. Caught my attention while I was looking at the helpfile for annotate, which showed aliases "blame" ;)

Comment: Tovi7: I added it in February of 2008, so it was first in 1.0. http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/rev/07f2236c4dee

Answer (score 16):

If you are using TortoiseHG

```
hgtk annotate <filename>
```

Or by finding the file in the log, rightclicking it and selecting "Annotate file"

Comment: It's `thg annotate <filename>` now

Comment: "Annotate file" is a button with a # sign.

Answer (score 10):

I looked for this for ages in Tortoise Workbench; thanks to @artemb and @Steve Pitchers for pointing me in the right direction. Still took me a while to spot it.

[image]

Comment: To get to that view on the left showing the individual repository files, depress the little button showing in the upper left corner, right where your changed files usually are. Then hover over the numbers by each line and look way at the bottom to see the author in the status bar.

Comment: One can also right-click, Annotate Options > Show Author

Answer (score 10):

In tortoisehg annotate window, there is a new context menu to enable this.

see https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/1861/annotate-window-annotate-with-authors
[image]

Answer (score 5):

on the command line , you can use either hg blame or hg annotate.

```
$ hg blame -u -c -l Filename

-u --user                list the author (long with -v)
-c --changeset           list the changeset
-l --line-number         show line number at the first appearance
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
hg blame <file name> | grep -A10 -B10 "<piece of code from the line of interest>"
```

It will show who made the change to the line, including 10 lines above and 10 lines below the line you are interested in.